# Explanation for in loop javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

I'm having trouble understanding the way this **for in** loop works.

```
function createSimpleNode(name, options, text) {
         var node = document.createElement(name); 

        for (var o in options) { 
                 node.setAttribute(o, options[o]);
        }

        if (text) { 
                node.innerHTML = text;
        }

        return node; 
}
```

Comment: For In - iterates over a collection just, it will pull the first type off the list and let use it in the following code block.
Using o in options[o] will never set, as it is not an Index in the collection.
Maybe look at [JavaScript Loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_forin_loop.htm)

Comment: updated my answer for example of object and array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**For in loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) gives a way to iterate over an object or array with each value and key.

It can be applied over an `object` or `Array`.

## For an Object

For an object it gives each `key`  in the object as the `ITER variable.` Using this variable you can get the corresponding value from object.

```
var options = {a:1,b:2};

for (var key in options) { 
    console.log(o,options[key]);
}
```

Will Iterate over the `options` object and print each `key` and it's value.

```
a 1 //first key is a and options["a"] is 1
b 2 //first key is a and options["b"] is 2
```

## For an Array

For an array it gives each `index` in the array as the `ITER variable.` Using this variable you can get the corresponding element from array.

```
var options = ["a","b"];

for (var index in options) { 
    console.log(index,options[index]);
}
```

Will Iterate over the `options` array and print each `index` and element on given index. Output will be:-

```
0 a //first index is a and options[0] is a
1 b //second index is a and options[1] is b
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). it iterates over the properties of an object (`options`, in this case), and allows you access the said property in each iteration using the `[]` operator.

In your example, you iterate over `options` properties, and set them all as attributes of `node`.